# Spilt long "or" condition statement into a function C#

Tags: c#, conditional-statements

Original i have a IF condition function in my code, see below:

```
 //check property and/or i.Prod and then show the popup
 void _incident_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e) </i>
    {

       // MessageBox.Show(e.PropertyName); //Check what property name is


        /*
        if (_incident.ProductID == 182 ||_incident.ProductID ==1959 && _triggerPopup) //If product ID is 183 in incident 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The GO Classic will soon be end of life, make sure you propose the customer to buy a new device and offer maximum 20% discount to reward his/her loyalty (NOTE: refurbished devices are not included in this offer).");
            _triggerPopup = false; //Do not pop up
        }*/


    }
```

Currently, we need to add more ProductID into if condition, like 20 more ProductID into if condition, the code will look mess and untidy.

I am thinking i can build a function to refactor the code a bit;

```
if (checkProductID(_incident.ProductID)&& _triggerPopup) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The GO Classic will soon be end of life, make sure you propose the customer to buy a new device and offer maximum 20% discount to reward his/her loyalty (NOTE: refurbished devices are not included in this offer).");
            _triggerPopup = false; //Do not pop up
        }

    }
    protected Boolean checkProductID(int productID)
    {
        switch (productID)
        {
            case "182":
                return true;
                break;

        }
    }
```

I am wondering whether this is right way to do that. Do i write this checkProductID function correct? does other better way to do that? thanks

Cheers,
Qing

Comment: It sounds to me like these IDs should not be represented as constants in code, but rather as data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably use properties (along with enums):

```
public enum ProductStates
{
  OutOfOrder=0,
  InStock=1,
  New=2
  ...
}

public class Incident
{
  public string ProductStatusMessage 
  {
    get
      {
        switch (this.ProductID)
         {
           case (int)ProductStates.OutOfOrder:
             return "This product will soon be out of order.";
             break;
           case (int)ProductStates.InStock:
             return "This product has a 10% discount!";
             break;
             ...
           default:
             return string.empty;
             break;
         }
      }
    ...
  }
```

And in your code:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_incident.ProductStatus))
{
  MessageBox.Show(_incident.ProductStatusMessage);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Factoring out logic into a separate method is normally a good design choice. This makes your code easier to read and easier to maintain, while making it possible to reuse the logic elsewhere. So this is probably a good idea.

With that said, there are a few problems with your approach.

The main problem is that you are hard coding id numbers into your method. This means that you will have to change your code each time your data changes. In most cases this will be clumsy and inefficient. Is it not possible to check your product database or something to see if you should trigger the popup?

A smaller problem is that you are comparing ints to strings in your code. This is probably just a typing error in your code example, but you should be aware that this is not a good idea. :-)

Comment: Hi Rune, thx for point out the code problems. Hopefully, the product id won't change in our Database. Yes, i made a wrong comparison in Switch case code.

Answer (score 1):

what about `.Contains()`?

```
int[] productIDs = { 5, 7, 10, 11 };

if (productIDs.Contains(_incident.ProductID))
{
}
```

Comment: hi Bazz, _incident.ProductID is int, does .Contains() function also compare int?

Comment: @QLiu it does, it compares any Type really, because it is an extension method that looks at the type of array or collection that it is used on. Since I use it on an Array of ints it works for your int `_incident.ProductID` For more info, have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5cf1d56.aspx

Comment: Error 1 'int[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments Here is my error message

Comment: Hi I solved the problem, however, the messagebox execute 4 times . //check property and/or i.Prod and then show the popup
            _findProduct = productIDs.ToList().Contains(_incident.ProductID.Value);
            if (_findProduct && _triggerPopup)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Test 11 This device might already be Out Of Warranty, make sure you propose the customer to buy a new device and offer maximum 20% discount to reward his/her loyalty (NOTE: refurbished devices are not included in this offer).");
                _triggerPopup = false; //Do not pop up
            }

Answer (score 0):

Just as an idea you can create a dictionary of `Dictionary<int,bool>` where the key is the productid, and then check with:
`dict.TryGetValue(...` if the product is classified and is classified as true, or, maybe better depending if you need just to store the "good" products:

```
HashSet<int> goodProducts = new HashSet<int>();
```

then you can just check if the product belong to that set by using `goodProducts.Contains(_incident.ProductID)`

Comment: Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<int>' does not contain a constructor that takes '18' arguments

Comment: You have to call add for each element to add in the set.

Answer (score 0):

Basically yes,

but: I assume you have the product master data available at that point, so I would add a flag to the product data. Then you can manage it all by maintaining the master data.

Magic numbers + constants in a code are pretty bad.

If this is not possible, create an RetiredProducts class that holds the retired product id's . such you cn reference the same data from all over your code.

hth

Mario